# How to set checkbox to true with Trigger when related objects are created

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex, salesforce-communities

[image]
This is relation between two obj. I want to code a trigger which makes Enrolled field from false to true (unchecked to checked) when Student is created with College record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need code for this. A formula field of type Checkbox and value `!ISBLANK(College__c)` would be enough.

Or workflow field update / flow / process builder with condition `ISNEW() || ISCHANGED(College__c)` and action `Enrolled = College not equal to blank`

If you're sure it needs code - this is decent start (but ideally you'd move logic to helper class, don't keep it straight in trigger)

```
trigger StudentTrigger on Student__c (before insert, before update){
    for(Student__c s : trigger.new){
        s.Enrolled__c = s.College__c != null;
    }
}
```